# Distinguish the name and namespace

Tags: namespace

Reference to 'namespace', in [Namespace - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace):

> In computing, a namespace is a set of symbols that are used to
>   organize objects of various kinds, so that these objects may be
>   **referred to by name**. Prominent examples include:
>
> - file systems are namespaces that assign names to files;[1]
> - some programming languages organize their variables and subroutines in namespaces;
> - computer networks and distributed systems assign names to resources, such as computers, printers, websites, (remote) files, etc.

I could grasp the idea of **referred to by name** and understand **name**,

Nevertheless, I struggled but failed to distinguish 'namespace' and 'name',
what's the space in 'namespace'?

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking.  Do you have a problem distinguishing between the concepts of “name” and “namespace”, or are you just questioning why a namespace is *called* a “namespace”?

Comment: The distinction between a set and its members is not always intuitive, especially if they have some characteristics in common. @muru's answer below is a good one, but you might find it easer to think of prefixes and suffixes. If you had two function definitions called `bar()` and `baz()`, and you put them into the class definition for the `foo` class, then - in many programming languages - they would be automatically placed within the class's namespace, becoming `foo.bar()` and `foo.baz()`. See how the namespace became the prefix and the names became the suffix of the qualified name?

Comment: On a different note, it isn't clear from your question how you think this - or indeed [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436110/the-theory-behind-builtin-input) - relates to Unix or Linux. Perhaps [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) would be a more appropriate venue for them?

Answer (score 1):

*Space* here is used in a sense similar to the [mathematical concept of *space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)):

> In mathematics, a space is a set (sometimes called a universe) with
>   some added structure.

A *namespace* is a set of names.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also read the second paragraph of [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace)?

> Namespaces are commonly structured as hierarchies
>   to allow reuse of names in different contexts. 
>   As an analogy, consider a system of naming of people
>   where each person has a proper name,
>   as well as a family name shared with their relatives. 
>   If the first names of family members are unique only within each family,
>   then each person can be uniquely identified
>   by the combination of first name and family name;
>   there is only one Jane Doe, though there may be many Janes. 
>   Within the namespace of the Doe family,
>   just “Jane” suffices to unambiguously designate this person,
>   while within the “global” namespace of all people,
>   the full name must be used.

So in this example “Jane” is a name and “Doe” is a namespace.