# The theory behind builtin `input

Tags: python

`

There's an example in  [2. Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

```
    >>> s = input('--> ')  
    --> Monty Python's Flying Circus
    >>> s  
    "Monty Python's Flying Circus"
```

Though I understand how to use `input`, cannot understand it's princile intuitively.
How does `input` magically stop to wait me and know I am texting in?

Comment: When you posted this question, how did you ‘‘magically’’ know to stop typing and wait for a response?   Seriously, if you understand how to use `input`, what do you not understand?

Comment: The same way Python knows to print the value of `s` when you typed in `s` and pressed Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` is waiting for you to enter something because that's part of [its documented function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> **input([prompt])**
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a
>   trailing newline. The function then reads a
>   line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing
>   newline), and returns that. When `EOF` is read, `EOFError` is raised.

So looking at the example given:

```
s = input('--> ')
```

You're calling the `input()` function, which does the following:

1. Prints the optional prompt argument (`-->`) to standard output (in this case is your console);
2. Reads a line from standard input (ending when you supply a newline by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>);
3. Either:

   a. Removes the trailing endline from the input and converts the remainder to a string (if an end of file condition has not been detected)

   b. Raises an `EOFError` error (if an end of file condition has been detected)
4. Returns the string.

The returned string is then stored in a variable called `s`. In a non-interactive program, if you wanted to display the value stored in `s`, you would have to use:

`print(s)`

Instead of simply `s`.